# jQuery stacking and unstacking triggers

Tags: jquery, triggers, jquery-on, jquery-trigger

The following code works. It allows you to press the enter and escape buttons. Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nfyWm/)

```
$(document).on('keydown', function(e){
    if (e.which == 13){
        // Enter Key pressed
    }
});
$(document).on('keydown', function(e){
    if (e.which == 27){
        // Esc Key pressed
    }
});
```

My question is how would I remove the binding for just the enter key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

e.preventDefault(), and return false; in the function

```
$(document).on('keydown', function(e){
    if (e.which == 13){
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```

or if you mean just the event binding

```
$(document).off('keydown');
```

if you mean just for that particular binding you can set a namespace

```
$(document).on('keydown.mykeydown'...
$(document).off('keydown.mykeydown');
```

Comment: The first one seems okay, little long. I may look into the last one, I have never declared a namespace, but it seems to me most like what I want. Is that `.on('keydown.mykeydown')...` the declaration? or only the binding?

Comment: well the first one is just incase you want the enter to be ignored, which is what i thought at first but then saw that you mentioned bind

Comment: And as preventDefault and return false do the same thing in this case, you only need one of them, preferably the first one.

Comment: Then the first one is not what I would like. I would just like to remove my logic for what happens when it gets pressed, and give control (default action) back to the web browser